# Mediaelement.js aspect ratio 2.35

Tags: mediaelement.js

When using the media player from Yootheme's widgetkit, which is using Mediaelement.js, I noticed that the script calculates the height of the video player based upon the width of a poster frame.

I have set the width of the poster frame to 940px and Mediaelement.js adds the height as 528px.
That would normally be ok if the aspect ratio of the video and the poster image was 16:9. However, I am working in 2.35.

Due to having a responsive template I cannot set the height of the div containing the video as this would affect the template when viewed on tablets/phones.

Is it possible to change the calculation within the Mediaelement.js to reflect the aspect ratio?

Comment: Noticed that this only happens in FF. Is there a fix for FF?

Answer (score 0):

I am not being too descriptive in this but if you init as JS (not the jquery method) then you can use the methods that MEjs has to offer:

setVideoSize, sets the video size.
setPlayerSize, sets player size.

```
meVideo.media.setVideoSize( screen.width , screen.height);
meVideo.setPlayerSize( screen.width , screen.height);
```

JS:

```
meVideo = new MediaElementPlayer('#mediaElement',{
            defaultVideoWidth: '100%',
            defaultVideoHeight: '100%',
            videoWidth: '100%',
            videoHeight: '100%',
            loop: false,
            enableAutosize: true,
            features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'],
            success: function(media, node, player) {
                 var events = ['loadstart', 'play','pause', 'ended', 'loadeddata', 'loadedmetadata', 'progress', 'canplay'];
                 for(var i=0, il=events.length; i<il; i++){
                    var eventName = events[i];
                    media.addEventListener(events[i], function(e) {
                        console.log(eventName);
                    });
                 };

            },
            error: function () { 
                console.log('Error Loading Video');
            }
        });
```

html:

```
<video id="mediaElement" poster="{{image.src}}" controls="controls" preload="auto">
                <!-- MP4 source must come first for iOS -->
                <source type="video/mp4" src="{{mp4_url}}" />
                <!-- WebM for Firefox 4 and Opera -->
                <source type="video/webm" src="{{webm_url}}" />
                <!-- OGG for Firefox 3 -->
                <source type="video/ogg" src="{{ogg_url}}" />
                <source type="video/flv" src="{{flv_url}}" />
                <!-- Fallback flash player for no-HTML5 browsers with JavaScript turned off -->
                <object scale="noborder" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ STATIC_URL }}js_scss/libs/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">       
                    <param name="movie" value="{{ STATIC_URL }}js_scss/libs/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
                    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&poster={{image.src}}&file={{flv_url}}" />      
                    <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
                    <img src="{{image.src}}" alt="{{image.credit}}" title="No video playback capabilities" />
                </object>
        </video>
```